# How to filter nested data in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my detail view I have followig result

```
{ // measure object
    "id": 5,
    "name": "co",
    "averages": [ // list of averages
        {
            "start": "2016-05-15T12:18:15Z",
            "end": "2016-05-15T12:18:16Z",
            "value": 22.0,
            "length": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to dispay in `averages` filtered data e.g 20 < value < 30.
How to realize it?

View:

```
class MeasuresList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.DetailedMeasureSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Measure.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter it when you are reading it from the database

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Measure.objects.filter(averages__value__range=(20.0, 30.0))
```

Comment: I need to filter averaves - nested to measure object